# NSDateFormatter "dateFromString" returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to get the date from string "07:00 PM" using below code but its returning me nil always. Any help?

```
let hr12Formatter : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
hr12Formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
hr12Formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

hr12Formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let hr12Date : NSDate = hr12Formatter.dateFromString(inputTimeString)!
```

Comment: Just remove those two lines date and time style. Just keep the dateFormat and set `hr12Formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")`

Comment: Thanks Leo!! It works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove those two lines date and time style, keep the dateFormat and set your date formatter locale to `en_US_POSIX`

**Swift 3 or later**

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.defaultDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())  // add this if you would like to use todays date as default
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let inputTimeString = "07:00 PM"
if let hr12Date = formatter.date(from: inputTimeString) {
    print(hr12Date.description(with: .current))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let timeString =  "07:00 PM"
let hr12Formatter : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
hr12Formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let hr12Date : NSDate = hr12Formatter.dateFromString(timeString)!
```

Comment: You probably want `hh:mm a` since the hour is two-digits.

Comment: You may check this http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: What about it? `hh` is for a two-digit 12-hour value. `h` is for a single-digit 12-hour value.

Comment: @rmaddy I've ran this code in **playground** ,with`hh` or `h` just print the same result, but I think `hh` is more accurate, since is for zero padding.Thanks for your correct.

Comment: The `hh` versus `h` would be far more important creating a string from date. When creating a date from a string, it seems the `h` can handle the leading zeros just fine.